# How does Magic the Gathering play differently with proxies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

I was once a kitchen table Magic: the Gathering player, but I quit because the cost of buying enough singles and packs to create a competitive deck (or even a fun kitchen table deck) was simply too high. Furthermore, it seemed like the person who spent the most money on packs and singles would win the most games, and I did not want to spend ~$300 on just one deck.

So I was wondering, if I convinced my friends to use proxies instead of using regular cards, would it make the game play solely based on who is the best deckbuilder (or netdecker!), or would using proxies hurt the game by ruining the TCG aspect of the game? Also, what house rules permitting proxies have you used?

Comment: There's no good way to answer this as it's purely opinion. It all depends on what you and your friends personally find fun. If you think it's fun to play with the best cards MTG has to offer, then of course it will be more fun with proxies. If you think the fun lies in building whatever decks you can with whatever cheap cards you have lying around, then it will be more fun without proxies.

Comment: As Gendolkari says: this is very much opinion based and depends on your wants and needs as a player or playgroup.
As for the rules regarding proxies, these can be kept relatively simple, but again this depends on your wants and needs. In my playgroup we have the following house rules regarding proxies. Any number of cards in a Modern deck can be proxied, but we don't allow proxies in Commander or paper Pauper; we don't play Standard. It must be clear to all players which cards are proxies and which card each proxy represents. Apart from this we follow the usual deck building rules.

Comment: cheap decks can potentially be very good. just google a bit for "budget decks" or something. there used to be a "building on a budget" column on the wizards site. you can still find it in their archive here: http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/archive.aspx?tag=buildingonabudget&description=building%20on%20a%20budget . And in my opinion, if not playing in sanctioned tournaments and just playing kitchen table magic is more about fun than winning. I for instance really like decks with weird combo's that I like even if I would only win 1 in 10 games with it.

Comment: You could also just play pauper, where you only use commons.

Comment: I have (hopefully) made the question more objective and wonder if it can be  re-opened in its current form.

Comment: It is still just asking how is magic played if you have access to every card in the game and the answers will vary from person to person

Comment: I think this question is answerable in its current form. As long as we stick to experiences we had rather than opinions we guess may be true, answers might be within SE's rules.

Comment: Depending on the context there may actually be an answer. I think that that if you play an eternal or casual format (meaning most/all cards are legal), then you will run into the issue that your kitchen-table meta will end up in a state where you have a limited number of decks which are simply "the best" and the only variety is in how they deal with eachother. On the other end of the spectrum is a fluid format like Standard, where that effect will be less pronounced and the proxies will simply allow you to play the "best" version of the deck with all intended cards, which can be instrumental.